# Autofac - DataContext not being disposed at end of lifetime scope

Tags: c#, autofac, unit-of-work

I have a command-line program which is importing data into my system. Because it's inserting data into many tables, I require change tracking. To try and prevent the job from slowing down over time, I have used Autofac (my dependency injection framework) to create an inner lifetime scope from which I resolve dependencies. At the end of each batch, I recreate the lifetime scope and get new instances of my dependencies. The problem is that when I do this, my DataContext which the UnitOfWork depends on is not being refreshed each time, leading to a situation where the job slows down and eventually terminates before completing.

I can see this when debugging by setting the 'Make Object ID' on my DbContext, e.g.

[image]

After each batch, the object ID remains $2, demonstrating that the DataContext instance is not getting a new instance. Why is it not getting a new instance?

My code looks something like this:

```
foreach (var batch in data.Batch(10))
{
    using (var scope = LifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(b =>
    {
        b.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>.AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterType<MyService1>.AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterType<MyService2>.AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }))
    {
        UnitOfWork = scope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
        MyService1 = scope.Resolve<IMyService1>();
        MyService2 = scope.Resolve<IMyService2>();
        Thing1Repository = scope.Resolve<IEntityBaseRepository<Thing1Repository>>();
        Thing2Repository = scope.Resolve<IEntityBaseRepository<Thing2Repository>>();

        foreach (var row in batch)
        {
            try
            {
                ParseRow(row);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JobLogger.Error(e, "Failed to parse row. Exception: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It was my understanding that when I get a new instance of my dependencies, the child dependencies will get new instances as well? Why is the original DataContext still hanging about?

My UnitOfWork looks like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : Disposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDbFactory _dbFactory;
    private DataContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    public DataContext DbContext => _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = _dbFactory.Initialise());

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.Commit();
    }
}
```

My DbFactory is responsible for creating a new instance of my DataContext:

```
public class DbFactory : Disposable, IDbFactory
{
    DataContext _dbContext;

    public DbFactory()
    {
        _dbContext = new DataContext();
    }

    public DataContext Initialise()
    {
        return _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = new DataContext());
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        _dbContext?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My services are registered by scanning the assembly when the program first starts by calling this method:

```
AutofacConfig.InitialiseJobRunner();
```

Inside this method, I register my types like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(lifetimeScope);
builder.RegisterGenericInstance(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>), typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>), lifetimeScope);
builder.RegisterAssemblyInterfaces(Assembly.Load(Data), lifetimeScope);
```

RegisterAssemblyInterfaces is implemented as:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle>
        RegisterAssemblyInterfaces(this ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, object lifetimeScope)
{
    return builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(lifetimeScope);
}
```

Comment: How is DbFactory registered?

Comment: I've updated answer to explain. When the program first starts, I scan the assembly to automatically register dependencies, then I create a lifetime scope. Then later when I start processing the record inside the loop, I create an inner lifetime scope where I had hoped I would be able to get a new instance of DataContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you register assembly interfaces like below

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<object, ScanningActivatorData, DynamicRegistrationStyle>
    RegisterAssemblyInterfaces(this ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, object lifetimeScope)
{
    return builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(lifetimeScope);
}
```

my guess is that your DbFactory is also registered this way. In such case (according to: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope ) you will get the same instance of your factory as your child scope is not named. Try to add

```
b.RegisterType<DbFactory>.AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

in your loop or change DbFactory to always return new context in Initialise method instead returning the same if it's already instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, I earlier had tried this with no success, but I think I've found the problem. At some point inside the loop, I was trying to add an entity that was retrieved using a DataContext that was resolved outside of the loop. When I retrieved it within the loop with the refreshed DataContext it works. I'm going to test this with full data and will mark your solution as answer soon.